# Select a checkbox with variables wih Selenium

Tags: python, selenium

The address below is the xpath address.

`//label[@for="check54490"])`

The check box is checked when typed as below.

`driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="check54490"]').click()`

However, there are many check boxes that need to be checked, so I am going to make variables and check them.

I made a variable as below, but an error occurs.

```
umber = [54490]
for num in umber:
    elem = f'//label[@for="check{num}"]'
    elm2 = f"'{elem}'"
    xpath = elem2
driver.find_element_by_xpath(xpath).click()
```

the error message is as follows.

Is the approach good or is it impossible in the first place?

Please give me some advice.

```
selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidSelectorException: Message: invalid selector: Unable to locate an element with the xpath expression driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="check1000054759"]').click() because of the following error:
SyntaxError: Failed to execute 'evaluate' on 'Document': The string 'driver.find_element_by_xpath('//label[@for="check54490"]').click()' is not a valid XPath expression.
  (Session info: chrome=90.0.4430.85)
```

Comment: You missed closing the single quote in elem.

Comment: Show the HTML code of the element. I suspect the number will be keep changing so does it will keep failing. Also if the number is static then you can simply parameterized like `driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='check" + str(umber[0]) + "']")`

Comment: it's working, thank you. However, when multiple values are added to the number,  for example, `umber = [54490, 54491, 54521]` it is entered as follows..  `"//label[@for='check[54490, 54491,54521]']"} ` I want to choose a value for each.
Is it possible?

Comment: You have to pass 1 value each time to create valid xpath expression

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing it in for loop you can directly do it in the xpath for single value as below -

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='check" + str(umber[0]) + "']")
```

Now since you have asked how you can do it in case of multiple values consider the following code example -

```
umber = [54490, 54490]
for num in umber:
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='check" + str(num) + "']").click()
```

OR you can have each number in different variable -

```
xbuttonNum = '54490'
ybuttonNum = '54491'
zbuttonNum = '54521' 

driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='check" + xbuttonNum + "']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='check" + ybuttonNum + "']").click()
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//label[@for='check" + zbuttonNum + "']").click()
```

Alternatively you can customize your xpath unique for all the elements and iterate over them all at once like -

```
AllElementwithCheckString =  driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//label[starts-with(@for,'check')]")

for elem in AllElementwithCheckString:
    elem.click()
```